# Jabref+Texmaker: how to use .bib in another directory?

Tags: texmaker

I am really struggling with this, which seems not be very well documented.

1. I use JabRef. I saved my `.bib` file at

   ```
   C:\swp55\TCITeX\BibTeX\bib\my_bibl.bib
   ```

   because I use it in SW as well.
2. The objective is to use the same `my_bibl.bib` in TeXmaker. The question is how?

   - I went to Option -> Configure TeXmaker and added

     ```
     bibtex --include-directory="C:\swp55\TCITeX\BibTeX\bib
     ```

     in the Bib(la)tex box.
   - Then in my file I add

     ```
     \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
     \bibliography{my_bibl.bib }
     ```
   - I compile with the usual sequence PDFLaTeX-BibTeX-PDFLaTeX-PDFLaTeX

But I see the `?` symbols in my document. When I do BibTeX, I get

```
Process started

Need exactly one file argument

Process exited normally
```

Please help! I am sure if we have a well defined procedure, it would help many people.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you have a`.blg` and a `.bbl` files?

Comment: I see a .bbl file in my "build directory".

Comment: And no `.blg` (it's the log file of `bibtex` or `biber`)?

Comment: The error you get is the one that happens when you run "bibtex" without any arguments. In other words, what should be issued is `bibtex filename.aux`; but somehow you are running instead just `bibtex`.

Comment: Yes, I do have a (.blg). What are you suspecting???

Comment: Willie, thanks.  I see. I am definitely running bibtex (F11 shortcut in TexMaker). After I run it, I get : "Process started-Need exactly one file argument-Process exited normally". In fact, I see the "Bibliography" Title, but nothing behing and all ? in my \cite{paper}.

Comment: In the build folder I actually have: the pdf and txt, aux, bbl, blg, dvi, out , gz. I will appreciate any comment.